# Allow "hidden" scalar multiplication in R

Tags: r, matlab, matrix

I am translating a code from Matlab to R. In Matlab, one of the code line is

```
C=A*B
```

where B is a matrix and A is either a matrix or a scalar (for example, A=1) depending on certain conditions. And this works perfectly well since matrix*matrix or scalar *matrix is written the same way in Matlab (up to appropriate dimensions for matrix multiplications, which is the case).

However, in R, things become a bit more complicated. This becomes

```
C=A %*% B
```

which works fine... unless A is a scalar. Indeed, just writing

```
1 %*% diag(5)
```

outputs

> non-conformable arguments

while in Matlab, such a problem does not even exist.

Is there a way to translate my Matlab instruction `C=A*B` in R while still keeping the flexibility I need, as described above ?

Note, that setting A to the identity matrix wouldn't be satisfying: sometimes A is a scalar and cannot be changed into a matrix. I really need the "raw" flexibility described above

Comment: So, if A is a matrix you want matrix multiplication with B, but if A is a scalar then you want each element of B to be multiplied by A?

Comment: @user2974951 Yes, just as if you have 3*X, you basically multiply each element of X by 3 ;-). But I don't know in advance if A is matrix or scalar and I need to deal with both. In Matlab, no problem at all, * does the job anyway but in R :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own infix operator to deal with this issue. `tryCatch` is a way to deal with errors. If `%*%` returns an error, then the function will execute `x * y`:

```r
`%m%` <- function(x, y) tryCatch(x %*% y, error = function(e) x * y)
```

Tests:

```r
2 %m% diag(6)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    0
[2,]    0    2

matrix(1:4, nrow = 2) %m% matrix(4:1, nrow = 2)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   13    5
[2,]   20    8
```

Answer (score 1):

For your specific request, you can try

```
ifelse(is.matrix(A), `%*%`, `*`)(A, B)
```

and we will see

```
> B <- matrix(1:4, 2)

> A <- 2

> ifelse(is.matrix(A), `%*%`, `*`)(A, B)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    6
[2,]    4    8

> A <- matrix(4:1, 2)

> ifelse(is.matrix(A), `%*%`, `*`)(A, B)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    8   20
[2,]    5   13
```

Comment: I am not sure you understood well my request, I am doing either scalar multiplication or matrix multiplication but never element-wise matrix multiplication

Comment: @MysteryGuy Aha, sorry I misunderstood. You can see my update

Answer (score 0):

In an ifelse

```
mm=function(A,B){
  ifelse(is.matrix(A),list(A),list(diag(nrow(B))*A))[[1]] %*% B
}

A=1.3
B=matrix(1:4,2,2)
mm(A,B)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1.3  3.9
[2,]  2.6  5.2

A=matrix(1:4,2,2)
mm(A,B)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    8   16
```